# How To Read/Write Files From a SFTP Server in Python?

Tags: python, sftp

I am wondering how to read and write files to an SFTP server in Python. I tried searching for other Stackoverflow posts, but they all suggested using outdated modules like pysftp, or other modules that rely on pysftp.

Does anyone know any SFTP Modules for Python?

Comment: Why do you think that Paramiko is outdated?

Comment: I couldn't seem to get it to work, but I found the problem was with my server. I will change that, and see if it works.